# Django channels 'No application configured for scope type 'websocket''

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I am trying to implement a chat with Django and channels according to this tutorial (http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_2.html). I add channels and a chat app to installed apps. I make the following routings for a project:

```
# mysite/routing.py
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (http->django views is added by default)
})
```

Basically, I did exactly the steps from the tutorial. But after `runserver` I am still getting `ValueError: No application configured for scope type 'websocket'`, after going to a specific chat room. Can please someone help me?

Comment: You updated your settings file?

Comment: Yes, i did exactly everything from tutorial.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You appear to be missing the `websocket` key. The [tutorial](http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_2.html#write-your-first-consumer) says to add following imports and add the `websocket` key in `mysite/routing.py`.

```
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
import chat.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (http->django views is added by default)
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

Comment: Nice, actually it was in following section of tutorial. I ended finding solution one chapter before. Thanks.