# Websocket disconnect with Channels in Django

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I'm beginner with Django. I would like to use websockets with Channels. In this way I'm following this [tutorial](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_2.html) to create a simple chat.

I show you my files.

**chat/consumers.py**

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
import json

class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        pass

    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

My template file room.html :

```
<!-- chat/templates/chat/room.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Chat Room</title>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="chat-log" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea><br/>
    <input id="chat-message-input" type="text" size="100"/><br/>
    <input id="chat-message-submit" type="button" value="Send"/>
</body>
<script>
    var roomName = {{ room_name_json }};

    var chatSocket = new WebSocket(
        'ws://' + window.location.host +
        '/ws/chat/' + roomName + '/');

    chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
        var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        var message = data['message'];
        document.querySelector('#chat-log').value += (message + '\n');
    };

    chatSocket.onclose = function(e) {
        console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
    };

    document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').focus();
    document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').onkeyup = function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {  // enter, return
            document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').click();
        }
    };

    document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').onclick = function(e) {
        var messageInputDom = document.querySelector('#chat-message-input');
        var message = messageInputDom.value;
        chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
            'message': message
        }));

        messageInputDom.value = '';
    };
</script>
</html>
```

Root routing configuration :

```
# mysite/routing.py
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
import chat.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (http->django views is added by default)
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

And my routing.py file :

```
# chat/routing.py
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^ws/chat/(?P<room_name>[^/]+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer),
]
```

When I run my ASGI server and I arrive on the page **http://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/Test/**, I'm getting the following message error :

```
HTTP GET /chat/Test/ 200 [0.00, 127.0.0.1:2807]
[Failure instance: Traceback: <class 'ValueError'>: No application configured for scope type 'websocket'
C:\Users\kevin\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\autobahn\websocket\protocol.py:2801:processHandshake
C:\Users\kevin\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\txaio\tx.py:429:as_future
C:\Users\kevin\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py:151:maybeDeferred
C:\Users\kevin\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\daphne\ws_protocol.py:82:onConnect
--- <exception caught here> ---
C:\Users\kevin\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py:151:maybeDeferred
C:\Users\kevin\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\daphne\server.py:198:create_application
C:\Users\kevin\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\channels\staticfiles.py:41:__call__
C:\Users\kevin\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\channels\routing.py:61:__call__
]
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/chat/Test/ [127.0.0.1:2814]
```

Would you have an idea of the problem ? :)

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49283575/django-channels-no-application-configured-for-scope-type-websocket/53998603?noredirect=1#comment94834226_53998603) is similar, but no answer has been provided.

Thank you !

**EDIT**

I notice a strange thing, if I put wrong code in my file routing.py, the server doesn't notice it. It is like it doesn't read this file. For example if I turn the routing.py file like this :

```
# chat/routing.py
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^ws/chat/(?P<room_name>[^/]+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer),ezvzev
]
```

The server doesn't display any error message.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error. I assume we're both following the same tutorial.

For me it was the extra dollar sign at the end of the path in chat/routing.py:

```
# chat/routing.py
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path('ws/chat/<str:room_name>/$', consumers.ChatConsumer),
]
```

When the '$' was removed, everything worked.

Comment: The $ sign marks the end of a regular expression. For that to work, you have to use re_path, the re stands for regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my error ...
I put the file routing.py inside of the first directory : sitetest\
Whereas I had to put it inside of sitetest\sitetest\