# How to remove this error 'No application configured for scope type 'websocket''

Tags: javascript, django, django-channels

I am trying to build a chat app with Django but when I try to run it I get this error

```
No application configured for scope type 'websocket'
```

my routing.py file is

```
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter , URLRouter
import chat.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (http->django views is added by default)
    'websocket':AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

my settings.py is

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'mychat.routing.application'
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

when I open my URL in 2 tabs I should be able to see the messages that I posted in the first tab appeared in the 2nd tab but I am getting an error

```
[Failure instance: Traceback: <class 'ValueError'>: No application configured for scope type 'websocket'
/home/vaibhav/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/autobahn/websocket/protocol.py:2801:processHandshake
/home/vaibhav/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/txaio/tx.py:429:as_future
/home/vaibhav/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:151:maybeDeferred
/home/vaibhav/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/daphne/ws_protocol.py:82:onConnect
--- <exception caught here> ---
/home/vaibhav/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:151:maybeDeferred
/home/vaibhav/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/daphne/server.py:198:create_application
/home/vaibhav/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/staticfiles.py:41:__call__
/home/vaibhav/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/routing.py:61:__call__
]
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/chat/lobby/ [127.0.0.1:34724]
```

I couldn't find a duplicate of this question on stackoverflow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django channels 'No application configured for scope type 'websocket''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49283575/django-channels-no-application-configured-for-scope-type-websocket)

Comment: @Ahtisham my routing.py file has `AuthMiddlewareStack` , in that it is not

Answer (score 0):

problem could be in the asgi.py :

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
"http": get_asgi_application(),
"websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
URLRouter(
chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
)
),
# Just HTTP for now. (We can add other protocols later.)
})

Answer (score 0):

Those using centos,My issue was with redis. My system had redis version 3 updating it to redis version 6 or above got my django channels working. Redis was breaking in the background. Hope it helps