# Error in Django channels: ValueError: No application configured for scope type 'websocket'

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I am going to develop chat application using Django Channelsby following tutorials: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/part_2.html

**My Project level routing.py**

```
import os

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
import chat.routing  

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
  "http": get_asgi_application(),
  "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

**App level routing.py file**
from django.urls import re_path
from . import consumers

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^ws/chat/(?P<room_name>[^/]+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer)
]
```

**asgi.py file**

```
import os
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'core.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    # Just HTTP for now. (We can add other protocols later.)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you switched the contents of project level `routing.py` with `asgi.py` file. I recreated the working version of the project according to the [documentation you mentioned](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/part_2.html#write-your-first-consumer). Then I switched the contents of `routing.py` (project level) and `asgi.py`, and I got the same error as you on an attempt to connect to a WebSocket:

```
Django version 4.0.2, using settings 'django_channels_example.settings'
Starting ASGI/Channels version 3.0.4 development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
HTTP GET / 200 [0.01, 127.0.0.1:53043]
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/chat/lobby/ [127.0.0.1:53045]
Exception inside application: No application configured for scope type 'websocket'
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

The command I used in browser's JavaScript console to connect to the websocket:

```js
webSocket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000/ws/chat/lobby/');
```

---

You were also missing `.as_asgi()` in the app level `routing.py` file (i.e., `chat/routing.py`):

```
    re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi())
```

See: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/part_2.html#write-your-first-consumer

However, I doubt that this is what caused an error. The error you got is raised, e.g., when the `'websocket'` key is missing in the routing settings (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49283575/django-channels-no-application-configured-for-scope-type-websocket)), so be careful about that too.

Also make sure that your you have this in your `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'channels',
    'chat'
]

...

# Where `django_channels_example` is the name of your application
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_channels_example.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'django_channels_example.asgi.application'
```